# Laravel Update from 4.2 to 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm getting the following error when running composer install:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class App\Console\Kernel does not exist in /home/ubuntu/fusion/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:788
> Stack trace:
> #0 /home/ubuntu/fusion/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(788): ReflectionClass->__construct('App\Console\Ker...')
> #1 /home/ubuntu/fusion/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(667): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('App\Console\Ker...')
> #2 /home/ubuntu/fusion/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(265): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('App\Console\Ker...', Array, false)
> #3 /home/ubuntu/fusion/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(785): Illuminate\Container\Container->Illuminate\Container{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array)
> #4 /home/ubuntu/fusion/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(667): Illuminate\Container\Container- in /home/ubuntu/fusion/laravel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 788

This is what I have in my composer.json

```
    "require": {
            "php": "^7.1.3",
            "fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
            "laravel/framework": "5.8.*",
            "laravel/tinker": "^1.0"
        },
        "require-dev": {
            "filp/whoops": "^2.0",
            "fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
            "mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
            "nunomaduro/collision": "^2.0",
            "phpunit/phpunit": "^7.0"
        }
```

Thanks!

Comment: Check if console/kernel.php is inside of app-folder, if not it might be inside of your laravelApp.

If so, move console/kernel.php to app-folder.

Comment: Read through the [Upgrade guide](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/upgrade) for your versions on what to take care of

Comment: Make sure you are using a clean install of Laravel 5.6 instead of updating your composer.json, then copying the relevant files over. There are some files new to 5 that don't exist in 4.2 outside of the vendor folder. Though if you're doing this for 5.6, why not just go all the way up to 9? It's about the same amount of work, speaking from experience.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.